# openssl change type of custom OIDs fields in subject

Tags: openssl, cryptography, x509certificate, x509, oid

I need to create request with custom OIDs in subject.
I added this attributes in [new oids] section in openssl.cnf

```
INN = 1.2.643.3.131.1.1
OGRN = 1.2.643.100.1
```

in [ req_distinguished_name ] section I added:

```
INN                             = inn
INN_max                         = 12
INN_default                     = something like 012125125412
OGRN                            = ogrn
OGRN_max                        = 13
OGRN_default                    = something like 1532352362346
```

And I create csr with this OIDs but if I use "openssl asn1parse -in .csr"
I see that values of my OIDs 1.2.643.3.131.1.1 and 1.2.643.100.1 are UTF8STRING type.
But I need that OIDs is NumericString type. I can't find how set this values in NumericString.
How I can set values custom OIDs to NumericString type?